# foreach y mysql con update

Tags: php, mysql

tengo el siguiente problema

Realizo una consulta a mi base de datos y este es el resultado:
`select iduser, idbutton from botones`

| iduser | idbuton |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 1 | 8 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 4 | 8 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 8 | 1 |
| 8 | 4 |

tengo el siguiente problema

Realizo una consulta a mi base de datos y este es el resultado:

`Seleccione iduser, idbutton de botones`

| ID de usuario | botón de identificación |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 1 | 8 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 4 | 8 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 8 | 1 |
| 8 | 4 |

y tengo otra tabla:

| idusers | idbutonactive |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 1 | 12 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 7 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 8 | 7 |
| 8 | 4 |

Quiero hacer una actualización de la segunda tabla según los datos de la primera

```
UPDATE botones SET idboton=concat('9999',idboton) where idboton not in(4,6,8,3,5) and idusers not in(1,1,1,1,1)
```

¿Es posible pasar por la primera tabla y guardar los datos en dos variables?

EJEMPLO: `$one[]=(4,6,8,3,5) $two[]=(1,1,1,1,1)`

```
UPDATE botones SET idboton=concat('9999',idboton) where idboton not in($one) and idusers not in($two)
```

y así con cada iduser

Alguna idea?

Comment: Sí, es posible, pero debes intentar algo para que podamos ayudarte :) Utiliza los `[]` para los arrays y el comando `implode(',',$one)`

Comment: Muchas gracias! lo he usado, el problema es que a la hora de usarlo en el where in no tiene en cuenta si, por ejemplo, el boton 4 corresponde al usuario 1 o al 4

Comment: Ah, claro, con el `IN` todos los números son iguales, deberías hacer un `UPDATE JOIN` para que pueda discriminar por usuario

Comment: Pásanos el dataset en SQL con phpmyadmin, exportar, e indícanos lo que te gustaría obtener para esos datos de muestra

Comment: La solución está en saber como puedo recorrer el usuario y saber cuando cambia, es decir, usar un foreach y si el valor del usuario cambia dejar de recorrer y guardar los datos en una variable y continuar con otro usuario haciendo el mismo recorrido

Comment: Mejor en una consulta única en SQL, ¿no? Así se procesa todo en el servidor de MySQL

Comment: ¿Finalmente has conseguido que funcione? Si aún estás con ello, recuerda pasarnos el dataset en SQL y lo que has intentado para poder ayudarte